# Elm - tree - add branch to another tree - recursive forloop

Tags: for-loop, recursion, functional-programming, tree, elm

I want to move branches from tree to tree in Elm.

**For example:**

Tree 1:

```
A-1
- A-1-1
- - A-1-1-1
- - A-1-1-2
- - - A-1-1-2-1
- - - A-1-1-2-2
```

Tree 2

```
B-1
- B-1-1
- - B-1-1-1
- - B-1-1-2
- - - B-1-1-2-1
- - - B-1-1-2-2
```

I'd like to move A-1-1 under B-1-1-2-1 which should give

```
B-1
- B-1-1
- - B-1-1-1
- - B-1-1-2
- - - B-1-1-2-1
- - - - A-1-1
- - - - - A-1-1-1
- - - - - A-1-1-2
- - - - - - A-1-1-2-1
- - - - - - A-1-1-2-2
- - - B-1-1-2-2
```

*I'm new to functional programming. I can imagine how to do this with a recursive forloop in Python but I'm stuck with Elm.*

I can move one node easily but I don't see how to add the children recursively:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Canopy exposing (Node, append, children, leaf, mapChildren, node, value)
import Html exposing (Html, b, div, h1, h2, li, text, ul)
import List exposing (map)


tree1 : Node String
tree1 =
    node "A-1"
        [ node "A-1-1"
            [ leaf "A-1-1-1"
            , node "A-1-1-2"
                [ leaf "A-1-1-2-1"
                , leaf "A-1-1-2-2"
                ]
            ]
        ]


tree2 : Node String
tree2 =
    node "B-1"
        [ node "B-1-1"
            [ leaf "B-1-1-1"
            , node "B-1-1-2"
                [ leaf "B-1-1-2-1"
                , leaf "B-1-1-2-2"
                ]
            ]
        ]


tree3 : Node String
tree3 =
    let
        nodeToMove =
            "A-1-1"

        newParentNode =
            "B-1-1-2-1"

        -- append the node only but not its descendants
        treeWithNewNode =
            append newParentNode nodeToMove tree2

        -- type mismatch
        --        treeWithNewNodeAndNewNodeChildren =
        --            nodeToMove |> mapChildren (\child -> append 

        -- does not do what I was hopping for
        -- newTree =
        --    mapChildrenAt
        --        nodeToMove
        --        (\child -> append newParentNode (value child) treeWithNewNode)
        --        tree2

newParentNode child tree2)
    in
    treeWithNewNode


main =
    div []
        [ h1 [] [ text "Adding a branch to another tree" ]
        , h2 [] [ text "Tree 1" ]
        , viewNode tree1
        , h2 [] [ text "Tree 2" ]
        , viewNode tree2
        , h2 [] [ text "Move A-1-1 under B-1-1-2-1" ]
        , viewNode tree3
        ]


viewNode : Node String -> Html msg
viewNode node =
    let
        subNodes =
            children node
    in
    li []
        [ b [] [ text (value node) ]
        , ul [] (List.map viewNode subNodes)
        ]
```

My trial is here: 
https://ellie-app.com/7842F8jCLpCa1

I'm using Canopy here but I could use another library if it's recommended.

Comment: Please post the complete code here, including the definition of the data type and all your functions

Comment: @Bergi I've completed the code.

Comment: "does not do what I was hopping for" is not a very useful description of the problem. What does the code do? What would the equivalent python code look like, and what specifically is missing in Canopy to be able to do the same? Give us a little bit of help to understand the problem, then we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: @glennsl That's what it does: https://ellie-app.com/78tWMPxVPrca1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, it looks to me like you never actually extract `A-1-1`'s children from `tree1`, so let's start with that:

```
subtreeToMove =
    Maybe.withDefault (leaf <| "Failed to find node " ++ nodeToMove) <| get nodeToMove tree1
```

The [get](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/allo-media/canopy/latest/Canopy#get) function finds a node in a tree by value. Since there might not be a node with the specified value, it returns a `Maybe`, so we pass in a default value.

Next you find the target node in `tree2`, and attach the node with its children. I'll use [replaceChildrenAt](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/allo-media/canopy/latest/Canopy#replaceChildrenAt) here since the target node is a leaf:

```
treeWithNewNode =
    tree2 |> replaceChildrenAt newParentNode [ subtreeToMove ]
```

[All done!](https://ellie-app.com/78gktLWjzNza1)

Just mentioning this because you described the desired result as *moving* a node between trees: All data is immutable in Elm – so, after the move, `tree1` and `tree2` are still the same. So rather, a subtree from `tree1` has been copied into a duplicate of `tree2`

Comment: Thank you @O.O.Balance. This is working with replacingChildren. You are right, I wasn't extracting the children - I was only using the value. I did try with the node though (using `get` & `mapChildrenAt` and `append`) and the result was completely different - it actually ended up merging both trees together: https://ellie-app.com/78tWMPxVPrca1. I'll try again and post a different question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

My solution without `replaceChildrenAt` to preserve existing children.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Canopy exposing (Node, append, children, get, leaf, node, value)
import Html exposing (Html, b, div, h1, h2, li, text, ul)



-- add a node (and its children) under a branch in another tree


tree1 : Node String
tree1 =
    node "A-1"
        [ node "A-1-1"
            [ leaf "A-1-1-1"
            , node "A-1-1-2"
                [ leaf "A-1-1-2-1"
                , leaf "A-1-1-2-2"
                ]
            ]
        ]


tree2 : Node String
tree2 =
    node "B-1"
        [ node "B-1-1"
            [ leaf "B-1-1-1"
            , node "B-1-1-2"
                [ node "B-1-1-2-1"
                    [ leaf "don't remove me"
                    ]
                , leaf "B-1-1-2-2"
                ]
            ]
        ]


tree3 : Node String
tree3 =
    let
        nodeToMove =
            Maybe.withDefault (leaf <| "Failed to find node " ++ "A-1-1") <| get "A-1-1" tree1

        newParentNodeValue =
            "B-1-1-2-1"

        treeWithNewNode =
            tree2 |> addNodeAt nodeToMove newParentNodeValue
    in
    treeWithNewNode



-- treeWithNewNode


main =
    div []
        [ h1 [] [ text "Adding a branch to another tree" ]
        , h2 [] [ text "Tree 1" ]
        , viewNode tree1
        , h2 [] [ text "Tree 2" ]
        , viewNode tree2
        , h2 [] [ text "Move A-1-1 under B-1-1-2-1" ]
        , viewNode tree3
        ]


viewNode : Node String -> Html msg
viewNode node =
    let
        subNodes =
            children node
    in
    li []
        [ b [] [ text (value node) ]
        , ul [] (List.map viewNode subNodes)
        ]


addNodeAt : Node String -> String -> Node String -> Node String
addNodeAt node firstParentNodeValue toTree =
    --Canopy.toList ->
    -- [("A-1-1",Nothing),("A-1-1-1",Just "A-1-1"),("A-1-1-2",Just "A-1-1"),...]
    node
        |> Canopy.toList
        |> List.foldl
            -- acc is the updated toTree
            (\( nodeValue, parentValue ) acc ->
                append
                    (Maybe.withDefault firstParentNodeValue parentValue)
                    nodeValue
                    acc
            )
            -- initial value
            toTree
```

Visible here: https://ellie-app.com/79sd7H8fCjNa1

---

@o-o-balance's answer and this: https://elmprogramming.com/list.html#folding-a-list helped me a lot.